# Not able to copy html code of a webpage whose URL is given in the program using Async Task. Android Studio 3.4.2

Tags: java, android, download

I want to download the contents of HTML of a webpage using parallel thread using Async task. I learned the code from online tutorial and my code is exactly as per the lecture where it is working fine.

The try command in Async task is not working and the method doInbackGround() is returning "Failed" through catch.

I have printed the URL name in the method and it is showing in the logs.

```
I have provided the internet permission also through AndroidManifest.xml.

My primary guess is following three lines are creating problem though I would appreciate expert advice.



   urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream in=urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

package com.example.webdownload;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public class DownLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            URL url;
            String result="";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;

            try{

                url=new URL(urls[0]);
                Log.i("String",urls[0]);  // this is getting printed

                urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data=reader.read();
                Log.i("Data",Integer.toString(data)); //this is not getting
                                                         printed
                while (data!=-1)
                {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result+=current;
                    data=reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }

        }
   }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownLoadTask task=new DownLoadTask();


        String result=null;
       try {
           result = task.execute("https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/").get();

       }catch (Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
        Log.i("Result",result);

        }
}
```

I am not able to post Logs here somehow

Answer (score 0):

```
Since I could not post logs in my question I am posting them here:

These are the logs between URL printing in logs and to the Failed return through the method

I/String: https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.example.webdownload.MainActivity$DownLoadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:35)
        at com.example.webdownload.MainActivity$DownLoadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:18)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/Result: Failed
D
```